# Paypal sandbox all payments are pending and all pending status is unilateral

Tags: .net, vb.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am testing my IPN handler in the sandbox. I use my test account to send payments. All of the payments that I send are logged with this error

```
11/21/2014 10:50:13 AM: Error in IPNHandler.IsDuplicateID(): Cannot find table 0.<br/>
11/21/2014 10:50:13 AM: Error in IPNHandler: INVALID paymetn's parameters. Request: transaction_subject=15&payment_date=09%3A50%3A08+Nov+21%2C+2014+PST&txn_type=web_accept&last_name=g&residence_country=US&pending_reason=unilateral&item_name=Payment+for+goods&payment_gross=9.99&mc_currency=USD&payment_type=instant&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&verify_sign=AreWqcHdvcrjAVDpDrJUuRsO7ligA8OG-lfsIu-rC8RAcQNDzpUTG59y&payer_status=verified&test_ipn=1&tax=0.00&payer_email=landlordlookuptax%40gmail.com&txn_id=2XP22290RE646562T&quantity=1&receiver_email=Landlordlookup%40gmail.com&first_name=mike&payer_id=HUSR3RNKB25NJ&item_number=&payer_business_name=gfreg&handling_amount=0.00&payment_status=Pending&shipping=0.00&mc_gross=9.99&custom=15&charset=windows-1252&notify_version=3.8&ipn_track_id=97393d5e19d92
```

as you can see the `payment_status = Pending` and `pending_reason=unilateral`. I have disabled the "payment review" option for my account and I am using a sandbox account that I created. Some people said that the pending status is because the test account isn't verified but I am pretty sure that I did that. Any help on being able to send successful payments in a sandbox would be great! if you want to see any code just let me know. I used this site almost exactly to build my IPN handler http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19184/Use-of-the-PayPal-payment-system-in-ASP-NET?msg=4059063#xx4059063xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the receiver email  "Landlordlookup@gmail.com" address you are trying to use doesn't even exist . I mean you need to make sure that you have a sandbox account with the email address "Landlordlookup@gmail.com" .

If you send the payments to an email address that doesn't exist , You will get the **pending_reason=unilateral**

Comment: I thought I could use this account because it is my actual paypal account that I am using the sandbox on. Apparently I had to set the business email to landlordlookup-facilitator@gmail.com (created by paypal for sandbox accounts) to get successful payments.